flutter location fetching delay issue in ios fixed using geolocator 13.0.1
Delay in fetching location in iOS Flutter.
return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();

I tried above code. On android its working, but not on iOS iPad - there it showing indefinite loading.

'''
Future<void> getLocation() async {
setState(() {
  _isLoading = true;
});

// Optimized location settings with reduced accuracy for faster fetching
LocationSettings locationSettings;
if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
  locationSettings = AndroidSettings(
    accuracy: LocationAccuracy.reduced,  // Using reduced accuracy for faster results
    forceLocationManager: true,
  );
} else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS || defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
  locationSettings = AppleSettings(
    accuracy: LocationAccuracy.reduced,  // Using reduced accuracy for faster results
    activityType: ActivityType.other,
     // Reduced timeout since we expect faster response
  );
} else {
  locationSettings = LocationSettings(
    accuracy: LocationAccuracy.reduced,  // Using reduced accuracy for faster results
  );
}

try {
  // Check if location services are enabled
  bool serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      AwesomeDialog(
        context: context,
        dialogType: DialogType.error,
        animType: AnimType.scale,
        title: 'Location Services Disabled',
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0XFF0068B3),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 16.sp,
        ),
        desc: 'Please enable location services to continue.',
        descTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0XFF585F65),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          fontSize: 12.sp,
        ),
        btnOkText: 'Open Settings',
        buttonsTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14.sp,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        btnOkColor: Colors.blue,
        btnOkOnPress: () async {
          await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
        },
      ).show();
      return;
    }
  }

  // Check and request permissions
  LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      AwesomeDialog(
        context: context,
        dialogType: DialogType.warning,
        animType: AnimType.scale,
        title: 'Location Permission Required',
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0XFF0068B3),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 16.sp,
        ),
        desc: 'Please grant location permission to use this feature.',
        descTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0XFF585F65),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          fontSize: 12.sp,
        ),
        btnOkText: 'Request Permission',
        buttonsTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14.sp,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        btnOkColor: Colors.blue,
        btnOkOnPress: () async {
          await getLocation();
        },
      ).show();
      return;
    }
  }

  if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    AwesomeDialog(
      context: context,
      dialogType: DialogType.error,
      animType: AnimType.scale,
      title: 'Location Permission Denied',
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0XFF0068B3),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 16.sp,
      ),
      desc: 'Location permission is permanently denied. Please enable it from app settings.',
      descTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0XFF585F65),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontSize: 12.sp,
      ),
      btnOkText: 'Open Settings',
      buttonsTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14.sp,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      btnOkColor: Colors.blue,
      btnOkOnPress: () async {
        await Geolocator.openAppSettings();
      },
    ).show();
    return;
  }

  // Try to get the last known location first
  Position? lastKnownPosition = await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition(
    forceAndroidLocationManager: true,
  );

  if (lastKnownPosition != null ) {
    // Use last known position if it's recent
    latitude = lastKnownPosition.latitude;
    longitude = lastKnownPosition.longitude;
    print("lat and lon from lastknwnlocation ${latitude}${longitude}");
  } else {
    // Get current position with reduced accuracy settings
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      locationSettings: locationSettings,
    );

    latitude = position.latitude;
    longitude = position.longitude;
    print("lat and lon from currentlocation ${latitude}${longitude}");
  }

  if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
    await getCurrentPlace();
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    AwesomeDialog(
      context: context,
      dialogType: DialogType.error,
      animType: AnimType.scale,
      title: 'Location Not Found',
      desc: 'Unable to fetch your current location. Please try again.',
      btnOkText: 'Retry',
      btnOkColor: Colors.blue,
      btnOkOnPress: () async {
        await getLocation();
      },
    ).show();
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Error fetching location: $e');
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
  // More specific error handling
  String errorMessage = 'Failed to fetch location. Please try again.';
  if (e is TimeoutException) {
    errorMessage = 'Location fetch is taking too long. Please check your GPS signal and try again.';
  }

  AwesomeDialog(
    context: context,
    dialogType: DialogType.error,
    animType: AnimType.scale,
    title: 'Error',
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color(0XFF0068B3),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 16.sp,
    ),
    desc: errorMessage,
    descTextStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color(0XFF585F65),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      fontSize: 12.sp,
    ),
    btnOkText: 'Retry',
    buttonsTextStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 14.sp,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    btnOkColor: Colors.blue,
    btnOkOnPress: () async {
      await getLocation();
    },
  ).show();
} finally {
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
}

}
'''
